# Spacing between custom type right bar button items

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have four right bar button items added in a navigation bar.

```
UIButton *replybutton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [replybutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reply.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [replybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(replyAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [replybutton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 28)];
    UIBarButtonItem *replyBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:replybutton];
// there are 3 more buttons like this..

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:replyBarButton, replyAllBarButton, forwardBarButton, deleteBarButton, nil];
```

I want to give some extra spacing between these four bar button custom type items. I tried imageInsets,

```
replyBarButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 40.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

but it doesn't give spacing. Could someone advise me, how can i give extra spacing between four right bar custom type button items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` or `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`.

Here is an example:

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(replyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 28)];

// other buttons are created the same way

UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button2];
UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button3];
UIBarButtonItem *item4 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button4];

UIBarButtonItem *space1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *space2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *space3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[item1, space1, item2, space2, item3, space3, item4];
```

In this example, you are adding flexible spaces between every item. This will automatically space your items evenly.

If you want, you can also define the space:

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixedSpace.width = 40.0 // adjust this
```

Comment: They are "custom type bar button items"

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, but I have updated my answer to use custom items.